# Persist Firebase login with Node.js backend

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I've looked up how to check if the user requesting a certain view is logged in, many people suggest using `firebase.auth().currentUser`, but when I read the docs, it says that `firebase.auth().currentUser` just shows you if *any* user is logged in which doesn't really help me when I'm getting a request to my Node server, and I want to see if the user is logged in.

So what is the idiomatic way to let a user login in Firebase, keep them logged in, and have a function to tell you if they're logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the user is authenticating to Firebase on the client side, the typical approach is for the client to pass an ID token to the server to identify the Firebase user for the session.  See [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) for details on how to generate the ID token on the client and then verify it on the server.

Comment: So after a user logs in, how do they keep the ID token so that they can continue to pass it to the server during requests? Should it be stored in a cookie?

Comment: On a web browser, you could do that, sure.  In some implementations, the client only sends the Firebase ID token once per session (the first time); the server receives the token and validates it, and may generate its own type of token to send back to the client.  Then the client would store that new token that the server sent (in a cookie or something) and send that new token in future requests.  That approach means that you only have to do the relatively expensive parsing of the Firebase JWT ID token once on the server, you could save server resources under large loads.